# Design Pattern for storing class/function calls

Tags: c#, design-patterns

First of all, sorry could not find a good title :(

**Problem**
So let's say we have an object and we can apply different actions to manipulate that object and i want to persist this in the database.

As an example, we can define the following classes.

```
interface IAction{ object transform(object input); }

class Stretch : IAction {  }

class Shrink : IAction {}
```

And an object can have a list of IAction. Also each action can have a type that we defined.

```
enum ActionType { Stretch, Shrink }
```

When we retrieve the actions from the database then we need to do logics to checkh what is the type of the action to know which class to create.

If i just change the order of the items in the enum, then there is nothing that tell me my database has also to change and this can introduce breaking changes.

I'm trying to find a design pattern that will avoid this situation. Is there any?

Comment: Actions == plugins? If so, `enum` isn't way to go. Also, what do you want to store in DB? List of action types, or something else?

Comment: yes , you can take plugins as an example also. Well my question is what can we store in the db so it don't introduce breaking changes when my application change? I don't like this coupling with the data.

Comment: You can throw away enum, and use string constants as action type. So, there will be table like `ObjectActions (ObjectId, ActionId)`. When your application starts, it loads all `IAction` implementations, and every action must provide its id. If you need to do something with the object, you load action Ids from `ObjectActions`, and filter `IAction` collection using loaded Ids.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I do not understand the problem as described. Normally, I would not store/register actions or changes to an object itself and just let the objects maintain their current state.

When I want to store/register actions or create an undo/redo buffer, I would set up a logging or auditing mechanism. But I would design it completely separate from the basic storage/modeling structure, since I do not want to introduce such tight functional coupling in an application.

As with all problems, there might be many possible solutions. It is quite difficult to give an out-of-the-box solution for your problem.

You may want to look into somewhat more traditional solutions, like implementing a logging mechanism, an auditing mechanism and/or an undo/redo buffer in your application.

Choosing the best strategy depends on way more factors than described here and should be based on the overall design and architecture of your application (and the quality requirements that should be met).

By the way: In my experience, the future will certainly bring (unexpected) change requests that will break your current code logic and/or data structures. For that reason, it is important to keep everything in your application as simple and as elegant as possible while regarding all the required specifications. That will make the code more maintainable and it might also simplify future code and data migrations.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed i can use the undo/redo design but i need to persist the actions which introduce the complexity that the momento pattern does not solve.

Comment: There are various ways to store your objects' history and a solution based on the memento pattern might be useful indeed. Personally, I prefer to only store an object's current state and keep a simple log for manually tracking changes. When more sophisticated history tracking is required and previous versions of the object state are needed in the application logic too, I would (internally) keep a list of each object's previous states. Those states can be stored in the database too, of course, together with information about the performed action (like your enum) which triggered the change.